Conectar GeneXus con NetSuite con HMACSHA256 y Oauth 1.0
alguien sabe como poder realizar una conexión desde Genexus a NetSuite a traves de un post, ya he leido las reglas para el oauht1.0 con HMACSHA256, pero no he logrado realizar la conexión....Desde postman si me puedo conectar de manera correcta, y al parecer el problema lo tengo en la generación del signature...alguien podria orientarme?.
Muchas gracias por su apoyo. Saludos.
